# WHERE clause not working in SQL-query using mdbtools

Tags: php, ms-access, ubuntu, mdbtools

I've been working on a project using the LAMP server that requires frequent **read** of the MS-ACCESS database, stored in *.mdb file. The database has one table and about 40.000 rows in it.

I've installed `mdb-tools` and configured `unixODBC` to use it. First impression was positive:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
```

Worked fine, however returned a huge structure, that overflew my buffer and the tail of data was truncated.

```
SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3] FROM [Table]
```

Worked fine as well, but the amount of data was still on the edge of usability (barely didn't exceed the buffer). So I've tried to limit result with the `WHERE` statement, but neither

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [col1]=X
nor
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [col2] LIKE 'xxx'
nor
SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3] FROM [Table] WHERE [col1]=X
nor
SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3] FROM [Table] WHERE [col2] LIKE 'xxx'
```

isn't working. They just return empty structure.
But if the condition is all-matching - it works:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [col2] LIKE '%'
```

returned that huge bulk of data

I know that `mdb-tools` is quite an ancient solution, that provides read-only access - but that's ok for me. I just want it to work.
I've tried both versions - from sourceforge and from github.

Comment: Your statement seems allright, and actually you don't get an error. When you do a condition like : "WHERE [col2] LIKE '%'" or "WHERE [col2] LIKE '*'", do you get any results ?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention that I've tried them and they work fine

Comment: Is this .mdb file an active (i.e., not static or archival) database that resides on a Windows machine somewhere?

Comment: yes it is, I have a mounted shared directory on the machine I'm working on

Answer (score 2):

If `col1` is a text column then use `... WHERE [col1] = 'some text'` (note the use of quotes) for an exact match.

`... WHERE [col1] LIKE 'xxx'` is equivalent to `... WHERE [col1] = 'xxx'`.

When using `LIKE` the wildcard character `%` matches zero or more characters, and `_` matches one character, so

`... WHERE [col1] LIKE 'To%'`

should match "Toronto", "Tokyo", "Toledo", etc. ...

### Edit

The man page for the `mdb-sql` command of MDB Tools does claim to support `LIKE`, so I put together a test .mdb file with a table named [Clients] that contained

```
ID  LastName    FirstName       Email
--  ----------  --------------  ------------------
1   Thompson    Gord            gord@example.com
2   Loblaw      Bob             bob@example.com
3   Kingsley    Hank            hank@example.com
4   Thompson    Hunter S.       hunter@example.com
```

I did `sudo apt-get install mdbtools` on my test server (Ubuntu 12.04.02), uploaded the .mdb file and did the following

```
gord@pingu:~$ mdb-sql -p ~/ubuTest2003.mdb
1 => SELECT ID, LastName FROM Clients
2 => go

ID      LastName
1       Thompson
2       Loblaw
3       Kingsley
4       Thompson
4 Rows retrieved
1 => SELECT ID, LastName FROM Clients WHERE LastName LIKE 'Thomp%'
2 => go

ID      LastName
1       Thompson
4       Thompson
2 Rows retrieved
```

If you are having difficulty with WHERE clauses I would suggest running a similar test (with a small sample dataset) on your system using `mdb-sql` to see if WHERE clauses work in that context. If they don't work, then your MDB Tools is broken. If they do work, then we'll need to investigate further.

### Edit

I spent some time trying to recreate this issue in PHP on my Ubuntu 12.04 test server. I was unable to do so, only because I was unable to get the `odbc_` functions in PHP to work with `mdbtools` ***at all***. I could establish a "valid" connection (no errors) and I could "execute" a query (again, no errors), but I could not get any query to actually return results, not even `SELECT * FROM Clients`.

In searching for assistance with my problem I happened upon the Stack Overflow article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089782/lamp-php-accessing-access-database-with-odbc-with-mdbtools-driver), which further discouraged me from pursuing the matter further.

Instead, since this is apparently an active Access database hosted on a Windows machine, I personally would opt for using [ODBTP](http://odbtp.sourceforge.net/index.html). It is a free (GPL) TCP/IP protocol that allows you to pass queries to a Windows machine, which then submits the query via *its* ODBC driver and passes the results back to you.

It does require that a service be installed and run on the Windows machine, and the PHP client component must be compiled on Linux boxes, but if those requirements aren't too daunting then it is a pretty robust solution to this type of problem. (I have used it a few times in the past.)

And while it is true that ODBTP hasn't been updated for several years, it still works: I tested it just now with my LAMP server running the following PHP script to query an .mdb file residing on my older Vista notebook:

```php
<?php
echo '<html><body><pre>';
echo "ODBTP test:\n";

$con = odbtp_connect('192.168.1.254', 
        'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\__tmp\\ubuTest.mdb;UID=admin;PWD=;');
if (!$con) die('_connect error: ' . odbtp_get_error($con));
$rst = odbtp_query("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE LastName LIKE 'Thomp%'");
if (!$rst) die('_query error: ' . odbtp_get_error($con));
while ($row = odbtp_fetch_assoc($rst)) {
    echo $row['ID'] . ': ' . $row['LastName'] . "\n";
}
echo '</pre></body></html>';
```

The results as displayed in my browser window are

```
ODBTP test:
1: Thompson
4: Thompson
```

Comment: Yeah, I do know it. Using wildcards doesn't help. (according to my understanding `'z%'` should match `'z40072'` or `'OPER%'` should match `'OPERATOR'`)

Comment: @khartvin So you're saying that **(1)** `LIKE '%'` returns all rows, but `LIKE 'x%'` returns none (assuming there's at least one entry that starts with 'x'), and **(2)** `WHERE [col1] = 'xyz'` fails to return any rows when you know that at least one row exists with 'xyz' in [col1]? If so, then your installation of MDB Tools and/or unixODBC may simply be broken.

Comment: Exactly.    As I said - I've tried 2 different versions of mdb-tools, so I assume it's not very likely that both of them are broken...

Comment: I've checked it - `mdb-sql` works fine, `LIKE` and `WHERE` clauses give expected results. However as I managed to find out, `libmdbodbc.so` doesn't make use of `mdb-sql` application, so it's possible that some functionalities were added to `mdb-sql` and not to the driver lib...

Comment: Thank you for that hint, I'll check that ODBTP solution, however I am pretty sure, that it will not be possible to install that service on the Windows machine. It's a closed production system, delivered to our customers by another company.    That company gives warranty for that system, but it's void if they modify the environment...    By the way - I was sure that there was some magic involved, when I managed to make that ancient `mdb-tools` work with `ODBC` :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while...

mdb-tools is CRAP.

---

We have ended up by writing out own Windows service listening to SQL queries on a port given and proxing them to Access by an ADO connection.

So if only you have such opportunity, I recommend you not to use dead mdb-tools.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sounds like you wound up implementing something quite similar to ODBTP after all....

Comment: That's right. However, our solution is simpler, as it does not require any special PHP-client.  The lesson learned is that it appears that there is no easy way to connect to the MS Access database without using some kind of Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sneaky suspicion that your WHERE col data contains some special characters like single quotes or double quotes OR there is some issues with PrimaryKey.

I'm using MDBTools and I successfully select cols from tables with wildcards, BUT when i try to select from a certain col that has some double quotes in the data, i get ZERO results.  When I run php blah.php on that particular col, I get the error

CRITICAL: can't find column with internal id ### in index PrimaryKey

Found that in the code on line 309, but still not past it...
https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/blob/master/src/libmdb/index.c