# unixODBC + mdbTools + PHP

Tags: php, ms-access, ubuntu, odbc, unixodbc

I need to connect a PHP script in a LAMP (Linux Ubuntu 12.10, Apache 2, MySQL 5, PHP 5.3) server to an Access MDB database (version 2003).

### 1. unixODBC and Driver installation

The Ubuntu 12.10 comes with unixodbc 2.2.14 package (http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/unixodbc). The installation was easy: apt-get install unixodbc libmdbodbc1 php5-odbc. This way I've unixODBC with the mdbTools driver and the ODBC PHP capability.

I've edited /etc/odbcinst.ini with the mdbtools driver:

```
[MDBToolsODBC]
Description = MDBTools Driver
Driver = libmdbodbc.so.1
```

I've edited /etc/odbc.ini with the Access datasource:

```
[FormPulmo]
Description = FormulariCDRPulmo
Driver = MDBToolsODBC
Servername = localhost
Database = /mnt/svrfit/cdr/bd_pulmo_hardlink.mdb
UserName =
Password =
port = 5432
```

Finally I tested from shell and it worked:

```
> isql -v formpulmo
Connected!
```

### 2. PHP connection

With PHP initialy all seems to work ok:

```
$link = odbc_connect ('formpulmo',"","");
$res = odbc_exec ($link,"SELECT * FROM exampleTable");
```

The first problem was trying to access tables with spaces in their names. Example: "example Table". In Windows I've to put that between brackets ([example Table]) but it didn't worked. Finally I found the solution:

```
$res = odbc_exec ($link,"SELECT * FROM \"example Table\"");
```

**Before this solutions all the browser response trying to do the odbc_exec were "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)"**

## 3. PHP problems !

But now I'm stuck with the UPDATE syntax. The normal query is:

```
$res = odbc_exec ($link,"UPDATE [Registre cancer de pulmo] SET CIP = 'example' WHERE CIP = 'example'");
```

The browser response is: "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)" (In Firefox: "The connection was reset").

### 3.1. Tried solutions

```
UPDATE \"Registre cancer de pulmo\" SET CIP = 'example' WHERE CIP = 'example'
UPDATE \"Registre cancer de pulmo\" SET \"CIP\" = 'example' WHERE \"CIP\" = 'example'
UPDATE {Registre cancer de pulmo} SET {CIP} = 'example' WHERE {CIP} = 'example'
```

Connect with different cursors:

```
odbc_connect ($odbcFormPulmo,"","",SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
odbc_connect($odbcFormPulmo,"","",SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER);
```

I don't know what more I can try :-(

Comment: There is an easy way to do that with simple java application which uses Jackcess library.see my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342165/unixodbc-php-update-statement-error/24418298#24418298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several weeks ago in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15896046/2144390) I did some testing on a setup almost identical to yours (Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 12.10) and found that I could not get `mdbtools` to work at all. I gather that *some* people can *sometimes* get it to *sort of* work, but IMO `mdbtools` is not reliable enough for production use.

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15896455/2144390) to that question I recommended investigating [ODBTP](http://odbtp.sourceforge.net/index.html) as an alternative. It is a free (GPL) TCP/IP protocol that allows you to pass queries to a Windows machine, which then submits the query via its ODBC driver and passes the results back to you. I have used it a few times in the past and it has worked very well.

Comment: It worked, thx! This solution is not perfect because it depends on a Windows machine, but it's better than nothing. Hopefully some day we will have a good and free odbc/mdb driver.

Comment: Hi, I agree... Tried to run a simple insert using MDBTools and got "SQL error: Couldn't parse SQL" error.