# WHERE + JOIN Not working in code igniter using ODBC

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access, odbc

Currently i am stuck with some strange issue. i am using Codeigniter and my database is `ms-access`. i am able to connect the database and get values with single query. but when i am trying to use `WHERE` or `JOIN` in the query it just give me below error :

```
Severity: Warning

Message: odbc_exec(): SQL error: Couldn't parse SQL , SQL state 08001 in SQLExecDirect

Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php

Line Number: 138
```

MY **database.php** file is here for odbc connection:

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=//var/www/html/***/****/****.mdb',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'database' => '/var/www/html/***/****/****.mdb',
        'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => FALSE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

i have tried all the solutions but nothing worked. Thanking in advance !!!!

**test.php (test file)**

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_states'; // Working query //
$query = 'SELECT tbl_Projects.*,tbl_Dispatch.* FROM tbl_Projects INNER JOIN tbl_Dispatch ON tbl_Dispatch.Dispatch_JobNumber =  tbl_Projects.project_ID'; // NOT Working query //
$mdb_file = '/var/www/html/******/gps_jobs/assets/*****.mdb';
$driver = 'MDBToolsODBC';
$dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver={$driver};DBQ=$mdb_file;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;";
$connection = new PDO($dataSourceName);
$result = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: There's a very faint possibility that the problem might be with your query, instead of with the database configuration.... perhaps if you showed us the query that you're trying to execute

Comment: let me add test file so you have better idea.

Comment: @MarkBaker : please check  the test.php file

Comment: MS Access can be weird, sometimes rejecting queries that are perfectly good. MS Access sometimes likes brackets to be inserted all over the place, to help it parse SQL queries. I've even seen Access crash on certain types of deeply nested/branched queries, when brackets were not included; whereas it would run when brackets were included (requirements are non-standard). Try putting brackets around the "ON" clause: SELECT tbl_Projects.*,tbl_Dispatch.* FROM tbl_Projects INNER JOIN tbl_Dispatch ON **(tbl_Dispatch.Dispatch_JobNumber=tbl_Projects.project_ID)**
See if that makes any difference!

Comment: @MatthewSlyman : Thanks for reply but it's not working.is there anything else i am missing here ?

Comment: @prakashtank: Every time I come up against a problem like this in Access, I open up the MS Access user-interface, and try building a similar query incrementally in "Query Designer". Try designing a similar query in Access Query Designer, and see what kind of SQL code it produces. Compare it with yours. I'll be interested to know the differences!

Comment: @MatthewSlyman: okay let me try.

Comment: @MatthewSlyman : in query designer the query is working fine and giving me the result.

Comment: To be clear, you pasted your query into SQL View, ran the query, and it worked fine? Whereas you run the exact same query via the ODBC driver, and get that error message?

Comment: There's another possibility. When MS Access is running in ODBC mode, the ODBC options and even operating-system-localization options affect the way in which ODBC queries are processed. For example, if the client machine and server machine have different date-formats (DD/MM/YYYY vs. MM/DD/YYYY), I believe that Access sometimes attempts to translate parameters when it shouldn't, or fails to translate parameters when it should. (I can't remember the details, but ODBC doesn't just pass the query through, unless you are using a "PassThrough" query!) Access/ODBC sometimes tries to be too clever!

Comment: @MatthewSlyman : the issue i can't understand is this :
single query is working. but when i tried to run with `WHERE` clause or `JOIN` it gives me error :( . thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: In order to help more, it may be necessary for you to be a little more specific about what is going on. Can you confirm that the query which gives errors via ODBC, works perfectly when a similar query is created within Access, and run natively in Access?
One other question: Why are you still using a MS Access database in **.mdb** format? **.accdb** has been around for nine years now… The latest versions of Access are supposed to be using the SQL Server engine internally, which may be more reliable (or, shall we say, slightly less idiosyncratic and prone to crashing!)

Comment: @MatthewSlyman: it's clients requirement to use `.mdb` format.

Comment: @prakashtank: If you find that these issues are caused by idiosyncrasies in the legacy version of MS Access, you should charge them extra for the time you spent on this.
Have you tried simplifying the SELECT clause? Just: **SELECT tbl_Projects.*** If this doesn't work, try gradually transforming your query — start with something that looks like the query that works, and gradually add features until it breaks.

Comment: @MatthewSlyman: Yes i did check with `SELECT tbl_Projects.*` and its giving me the result. it break when i add `WHERE` clause

Comment: I don't see a WHERE clause anywhere here — do you mean the [JOIN] ON condition?

Comment: Consider changing drivers. MDBTools seems to behave subpar with some SQL statements. See these posts [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=995877) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342165/unixodbc-php-update-statement-error). If available try [PHP_PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php), sometimes need enabling in `.ini` file.